# Delphi to C# Question - I dont understand how to convert this small function

Tags: c#, delphi

The delphi code is:

```
function TMyPlugin.Get_BOUIEventsSupported: OleVariant;
var
begin
result := VarArrayCreate( [ 1, 1 ], varOleStr );
result[ 1 ] := ‘TEST’;
end;
```

I would imagine it's this in C#:

```
public override object BOUIEventsSupported()
{
    string[] result = new string[1];
    result[1] = "TEST";
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
public override object BOUIEventsSupported => base.BOUIEventsSupported;
```

But i'm not sure how to add an array to this version of it...Im lost now.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You shared override method , from where it is overriding? Can you share the relevant code with more explanation of the issue? Also can you also explain what's the Delphi code doing?

Comment: Your first function doesn't actually return anyway (`result` doesn't do anything in C#, unlike Delphi). If you want to return a bool array, You need to return `bool[]` instead of `bool`

Comment: Sorry, modified it...and Im stumbling through this small conversion. The Delphi code is supposed to be setting what looks like an array and the string is what will be looked for when an event happens.

Comment: I think im completely wrong now that i look at it, i believe its not even a function it makes mention to a set get...I will close this question for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> [VarArrayCreate](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Variants_VarArrayCreate.html) creates a variant array with the bounds given by
> Bounds and the element type given by VarType.

so for example:

```
  { Create a variant array of 10 elements, starting at 0
    and ending at 9. The array contains elements of type Ole String }
  Arr := VarArrayCreate([0, 9], varOleStr);
```

so in your case you are creating an array of one element and then assigning that element the string TEST.

The c# code should be:

```
public override object BOUIEventsSupported()
{
    object[] result = new string[1];
    result[1] = "TEST";
    return result; 
}
```

this is a dumb translation because both of the code versions does not make any sense in the first place.
the question that you need to answer now is who wrote that Delphi code? and what did he drink before that?